# is it a good way to return another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

when  read some javascript source, I found below code:

```
var fullname = function(){
     var shorts = { pos: "position", w: "width", h: "height", l: "left", t: "top" };
        return function(name){
          return shorts[name] || name;
      }
 }();
```

is it more effective or other reasons by returning another function? 
why not use:

```
    function fullname(name){
         var shorts = { pos: "position", w: "width", h: "height", l: "left", t: "top" };
         return shorts[name] || name; 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to

```
var shorts = { pos: "position", w: "width", h: "height", l: "left", t: "top" };

function fullname(name){
      return shorts[name] || name;
}
```

... in what it does.  But

```
var fullname = function(){
     var shorts = { pos: "position", w: "width", h: "height", l: "left", t: "top" };
        return function(name){
          return shorts[name] || name;
      }
 }();
```

... ensures that the hash/object `shorts`, is * **private** only to the function `fullname`* 
.

So to answer yor question, Why not

```
  function fullname(name){
         var shorts = { pos: "position", w: "width", h: "height", l: "left", t: "top" };
         return shorts[name] || name; 
  }
```

Here' `shorts` is hidden inside `fullname`, but as Dogbert points out, it's slower
because the hash `shorts` is *being created at each invocation*.

But this gives the best of both worlds:

```
var fullname = function(){
     var shorts = { pos: "position", w: "width", h: "height", l: "left", t: "top" };
        return function(name){
          return shorts[name] || name;
      }
 }();
```

`shorts` remains *private* to `fullname`
and at the same time, `shorts` is only instantiated *once*, so performance will
be good as well.

This is what they call an *IIFE* (Immediately Invoked function expression). The idea is
create a function `A` inside a function `B` and declare variables of use to function `A` 
within function `B`;s scope so that only function `A` can see them.

```
 var B = function(){
    // this is B
    // 
    val foo = {x:1}; // this is ONLY for A

    val A = function(arg0) {
       // do something with arg0, foo, and whatever
       // and maybe return something
    };

    return A;
 };

 val A = B();
```

As you can see, that's the same as

```
 var A = (function(){
    // this is in 'B'
    // 
    val foo = {x:1}; // this is ONLY for A

    return function(arg0) { // this is in A
       // do something with arg0, foo, and whatever
       // and maybe return something
    };

 })(/*calling B to get A! */);
```

In functionality, this is  exactly the same as

```
 val foo = {x:1};  // foo is visible OUTSIDE foo!

 val A = function(arg0) {
    // do something with arg0, foo, and whatever
    // and maybe return something**strong text**
 };
```

<s>I don't see any other use.</s>
So it's just a way of keeping variables private, and **at the same time**, 
not loosing performance.

(see [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript))

Comment: I'd like to add that this makes the first piece of code _much_ faster, as the variable is declared only once, than the second. Check [this benchmark](http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-no-closure-2) I created. (about 25 times faster for me in FF).

Comment: @Dogbert - thanks for pointing that out.  And wow, somehow with a name like yours, I cannot help but readily defer to whatever you say... ;-)

Comment: very good, I understood it very well after reading the answer. btw,the example of @Dogbert is awsome. good job!!

Answer (score 0):

Returning a function within another function causes a closure to be created.  In this case the inner function will have access to the outer functions scope, which includes the object `shorts`.